# Acumatica Override Opportunity Create SO action

Tags: acumatica

I have a need to modify the behavior of the Create Sales Order action on the Opportunity screen.

I'm trying to find the best / least intrusive method possible.  I have a snippet of the base code below.

The changes I need to make are relatively simple.  I need to populate some custom fields that exist on new SO.

What's the best approach?

```
public PXAction<CROpportunity> createSalesOrder;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.CreateSalesOrder, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntry)]
public virtual IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    foreach (CROpportunity opportunity in adapter.Get<CROpportunity>())
    {
        Customer customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.bAccountID>>>>
            .SelectSingleBound(this, new object[] { opportunity });
        if (customer == null)
        {
            throw new PXException(Messages.ProspectNotCustomer);
        }

        if (CreateOrderParams.AskExtFullyValid((graph, viewName) => { }, DialogAnswerType.Positive))
        {
            Actions.PressSave();
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
            {
                var grapph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpportunityMaint>();
                grapph.Opportunity.Current = opportunity;
                grapph.CreateOrderParams.Current = CreateOrderParams.Current;
                grapph.DoCreateSalesOrder(CreateOrderParams.Current);
            });
        }
        yield return opportunity;
    }

}

protected virtual void DoCreateSalesOrder(CreateSalesOrderFilter param)
{
    bool recalcAny = param.RecalculatePrices == true ||
                     param.RecalculateDiscounts == true ||
                     param.OverrideManualDiscounts == true ||
                     param.OverrideManualDocGroupDiscounts == true ||
                     param.OverrideManualPrices == true;

    var opportunity = this.Opportunity.Current;
    Customer customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.bAccountID>>>>.Select(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple override should accomplish your goal.  Below is an example, which injects custom logic into the event handler SOOrder.RowInserted, during the Create Sales Order action.  Then allow the action to finish normally.  This approach extends the action with your custom logic, while retaining base code of the Action.

```
    public class OpportunityMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    public delegate IEnumerable CreateSalesOrderDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter, CreateSalesOrderDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<SOOrder>((sender, e) =>
            {
                SOOrder order = (SOOrder)e.Row;
                SOOrderExt orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(order);

                orderExt.UsrCustomOne = "Howdy";  //assign anything you want here
            });
        });

        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wow, this looks exactly like what I need.  I actually need to pull data from the CROpportunity and CROpportunityProducts DAC and update custom fields on both the SOOrder and SOLine.  Would I just add a second addhandler for SOLine?  What's the correct way to reference back to the CROpportunity and CROpportunityProducts DAC that is associated with the SOOrder and SOLine?  Thanks so much for  your help.

Comment: I have this working for both SOOrder and SOLine by adding a second addhander.  For the SOOrder I just using the Base.Opportunity.Current to access the CROpportunity object.  Only thing I'm unsure is how to reference the CROpportunityProducts object associated with the SOLine in the RowInserted event.

Comment: I ended up changing the SOLine event to row updated, and then I matched the original Opp Product line to the SOLine based on the SortOrder.  The way the base code is written the insert happens before any of the data fields are updated.  This seems to work fine, although I'm still wondering if there is a more elegant approach.  Thanks